# Initializing a task with an Action that invokes with an int parameter

Tags: c#, .net, delegates, action, invoke

I have following constructor in my class, which initializes my task:

```
 public ReportGeneratorThread(Func<int, bool> getPermission, Action<object> a)
    {            
        this.action = a;           
        this.t = new Task(this.action = this.InvokedAction, this.cancellationToken);
        this.getPermission = getPermission;            
    }
```

The InvokedAction method, which will be invoked by the task is defined such as:

```
private void InvokedAction(object obj)
    {        
        Debug.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString() + " Task " + this.t.Id + " has STARTED Generating a report");
        this.GenerateReport();
        throw new ArgumentException("For testing purpose");                   
    }
```

The problem occurs when I want to invoke this method with an int rather than an object, since this is not accepted by the task. Is there any approach of how I can invoke this method with an int value with an:

```
Action<int>
```

Comment: Please show code that fail.

Comment: It doesn't fail as it is right now. The new Task() method does not accept an action with an int as lambda expression. I just want to invoke the method with an int as a parameter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you can't call `Action<int>` with argument of type object you need to convert it manually. Note that it would be fine if requirement is other way around - you can easily pass `Action<object>` where `Action<int>` is expected.

```
... new Task( v => intAction((int)v),...
```

You may need to handle cast exceptions if you can't guarantee that argument is always integer.

Answer (score 0):

Can you [box](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz2be5wk.aspx) your int before invoking?

```
int i = 123;
object o = i;
```

Comment: The problem is that I need to declare my Action with a specific int in an another class and call this constructor from that class.